# Skip first 'each" operator if condition does not exists

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having 2 each operators, one inside another

```
first_array.each do |index, values_1|
   second_array.each do |index, values_2|
      # --some action goes here--
   end
end
```

Is there any possibility to skip first each statement(`first_array.each do |index, values_1|...`) if `first_array` is `nil`?

This means if the `first_array` is `nil`, he omit first statement and executes only the second one:

```
   second_array.each do |index, values_2|
      # --some action goes here--
   end
```

Comment: Have `value_1` being used inside the loop? If so, what value should be used when `first_array` is `nil`

Comment: Please provide more context. What do you mean by **"skip"**? At a guess, based on the limited information you have provided, I would say to write a guard clause at the top of the method: `return unless first_array`.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make a lot of sense. If something has to be executed for each thing inside `first_array` than that something shouldn't be executed if there are no things. Are you sure your second `each` loop should be nested inside the first?

Comment: I assume that you are using `values_1` somewhere inside the nested `each` – what value would you expect if `first_array` is `nil`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: @Stefan. Yes, exactly. `values_1` is used in nested each. There won't be any value, so `null` will be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach without assigning default values to the `first_array`.

```
final_array = second_array

final_array = first_array.each_with_object([]) do |ele_from_first_array, result|
  second_array.each { |ele_from_second_array| result << ele_from_second_array + [ele_from_first_array[1]] }
end if first_array.present?

final_array.each do |sa_i, sa_v, fa_v|
  # fa_v will be nil if first_array is nil

  # Your code
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign a default value to your `first_array`, with the elements you want to be passed as `index` and `values_1`.

```
first_array ||= [[nil, nil]] # assign a default value if falsy
first_array.each do |index, values_1|
  # ...
end
```

The above will execute the contents of the `first_array` once, with the given defaults if `first_array` is `nil` (or `false`).

If you don't want to assign a default to `first_array` use `(first_array || [[nil, nil]]).each` instead.

Thank you for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963563/skip-first-each-operator-if-condition-does-not-exists/59963813#comment106045195_59963813) Stefan that updates the answer to fit the question edit.

Comment: Yeah, but then `second_array` wont be called. My goal is if `first_array` he omit it and calls only the `second_array` then.

Comment: @Viktor instead of an empty array, assign a one-element placeholder value, e.g. `first_array ||= [[0, nil]]` with `0` being `index` and `nil` being `values_1` within the loop(s).

Comment: @Stefan Good suggestion, I've updated the answer with it if you don't mind.